Community Digest footer links should be removed or YouTubified again in the preview
In the Community Digests page (on stackexchange.com), one can see preview of each newsletter.
The preview is the actual newsletter that being sent, not example or random, which is fine.
The footer of each Digest/newsletter contains links to unsubscribe, edit the user's email settings, and more. This is fine and expected in the actual email, however, in a preview this is not needed. It's not a real newsletter, you're not yet subscribed to it, and it's not sent via email.
In the beginning, those links linked to YouTube. Some didn't like it, some reported it as a bug, but that was by design, and personally I liked it.
I would like to have them either link again to YouTube, or another viable option is to just remove the footer altogether from the preview.
And can't leave such a request without a small surprise. ;)
